# Show that the measure is zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am asked to show that the $2-$dimensional Lebesgue measure of the graph of a continuous real function is zero.

Could you give me some hints how I could show it??

Comment: If you know Fubini's theorem, use it: the intersection of the graph with every vertical line has $1$-dimensional measure zero.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know Fubini's theorem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the restriction to a compact interval $[a,b]$. Use the uniform continuity of $f$ on the compact interval to show that you can cover that part of the graph by open rectangles of total measure $< \varepsilon$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: The uniform continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$ means the following $$ \exists n_0 \text{ such that } \forall n\geq n_0: |f_n-f|_{[a,b]}<\epsilon$$ right?? How can I show from that, that $[a,b]$ is covered by open rectangles??

Comment: No, that corresponds to _uniform convergence_ of a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions to $f$. Uniform continuity is related to continuity (stronger). Recapitulate the definitions.

Comment: Oh,yes..you`re right!! The definition of the uniform continuity is the following: $$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0 \text{ such that } \forall x,y \in [a,b] \text{ with } |x-y|<\delta \\ \text{ we have that } |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$ right??

Comment: Right. Now if you partition $[a,b]$ into finitely many subintervals of length $< \delta$, can you find a convenient cover of the graph by rectangles whose total measure you can estimate?

Comment: Maybe a rectangle of the form $$[x_i,x_{i+1}]\times [f(x_i),f(x_{i+1})]$$?? Where $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ is a partition of $[a,b]$

Comment: Not quite, there may be an $x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ with $f(x) > \max \{ f(x_i),f(x_{i+1})\}$. But similar.

Comment: Could you give me a hint to find the rectangle??

Comment: Consider $u_i = \inf \{ f(x) : x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]\}$ and $v_i = \sup \{ f(x) : x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]\}$.

Comment: So do we take rectangles of the firm $$[x_{i},x_{i+1}]\times [u_i,v_i]$$ ??

Comment: Try that. Where does it lead you? (Remember to use the uniform continuity.)

Comment: Let $u_i=f(x_k)$ and $v_i=f(x_l)$. We suppose that $x_i\leq x_k \leq x_l \leq x_{i+1}$. Then $|x_l-x_k|<\delta$ so $|f(x_l)-f(x_k)|<\epsilon$. Therefore the volume of this rectangle is $< \delta \cdot \epsilon$. Is this correct??

Comment: Or is this wrong??

Comment: That is correct. And if you sum up the volumes of all the rectangles, which bound do you get?

Comment: $$\sum_n v(R_n)<\sum_n \delta \cdot \epsilon$$
Does $n$ run from $1$ to $\infty$ ??

Comment: No, the sum is finite. However, it slipped my attention that using $\delta$ in the bound only works when you take equidistant partitions of the interval (you can do that, no problem), generally, $(x_{i+1}-x_i)\cdot \epsilon$ is the more convenient bound. If you sum that up, it's hopefully more evident what bound you get for the total area of all the rectangles.

Comment: So, you mean that I have to use the sum $$\sum_i (x_{i+1}-x_i) \cdot \epsilon$$ ??

Comment: "Have to use" sounds so negative. You know what $\sum_i (x_{i+1}-x_i)$ is, so that sum is easy.

Comment: This sum is a telescopic series which is equal to $b-a$, right?

Comment: Yeppa. So you get $(b-a)\cdot \epsilon$. Do you see how that takes you home?

Comment: Is it maybe as followed?? $$(b-a) \cdot \epsilon<\delta \cdot \epsilon$$

Comment: No, $b-a$ is usually much larger than $\delta$. But you can make $\epsilon$ as small as you wish (keeping it positive, though) and, with the appropriate $\delta$ get a covering of the graph above $[a,b]$ by finitely many rectangles of total area at most $(b-a)\cdot\epsilon$. Now, how do you need to choose $\epsilon$ for that to be less than a given $\eta > 0$?

Comment: Could we use for example $\epsilon=\frac{1}{\eta}$??

Comment: No, you want $$(b-a)\cdot \epsilon < \eta,$$ so the smaller $\eta$ is, the smaller you need $\epsilon$.

Comment: I got stuck right now...What is $\eta$ ??

Comment: $\eta$ is an arbitrarily prescribed positive number. To show that $\Gamma=\{(x,f(x)) :x\in[a,b]\}$ has measure $0$, we need [there are other methods when you have the appropriate theory, Fubini's theorem for example makes it trivial] to show that for every $\eta > 0$ we can cover $\Gamma$ by finitely many [countably many would work too, but here finitely many is simpler] rectangles of total area less than $\eta$. The uniform continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$ got us covers of total area less than $(b-a)\cdot \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Now you just need a sharp look to see that that is all.

Comment: I see!Could we formulate it as followed?From the uniform continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$ we have that $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x,y \in [a,b]$ with $|x-y|<\delta : |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. We partition $[a,b]$ into finitely many subintervals of length $<\delta$. $u_i=inf\{f(x):x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]\}$, $v_i=sup\{f(x):x\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]\}$. We have that $|v_i-u_i|<\epsilon$. We take the rectangles of the form $[x_i,x_{i+1}]\times [u_i,v_i]$ with volume $<(x_{I+1}-x_I)\epsilon$.

Comment: We take the sum of all volumes of the rectangles on $[a,b]$ and we get: $\sum v(R_n)<\sum (x_{i+1}-x_i)\epsilon=(b-a)\epsilon$. For $\epsilon=\frac{\eta}{b-a}$ we get $m(G)=v(\cup R_n)<\eta$.

Comment: Is it correct?? Or could I improve something??

Comment: At the end, you have $m(G) \leqslant \nu(\cup R_n)$, not equality. Then say that since $\eta > 0$ was arbitrary $m(G) = 0$ follows. And then you need to get rid of the restriction to compact intervals $[a,b]$, noting that the entire graph is a countable union of the graphs of restrictions of $f$ to compact intervals.

Comment: So, could I say it as followed??
At a compact interval $[a,b]$, we have that $m(G)=0$. Since the entire graph is a countable union of the parts of the graph that are seperated into compact intervals, so the measure of the graph is the sum of the measures of the parts of the graph, $\sum 0$, which is equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes, that's okay.

Comment: Nice!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)